# How to set controls in Xamarin Form to get a similar and relative UI in every phone screen sizes?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I want to make a UI like this:

[image]

This UI should correspond to different phone screen sizes.
I started to write this XAML code:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Frame HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="10"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Padding="0,40,0,0">
                <Frame HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="10"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MaxLength="30" Placeholder="User Name:" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MaxLength="30" Placeholder="Password:" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" IsPassword="True"/>
    <Image Source="User.png" Scale="0.6"/>
    <Image Source="Lock.png" Scale="0.6"/>
    <Button Text="Login"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I know that Those images must be in the Grid node above. But I cannot set those Entry and user/pass logos correctly. Those buttons are images in the resource folder.
Please help me to set a UI similar to this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One grid is enough, you can remove one.
You can refer to the following code:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="#1E90FF" Orientation="Vertical">

    <Grid Margin="20" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Frame HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

        <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="30" Placeholder="User Name:" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"  />

        <Image Source="head.png" Scale="0.6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Frame HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="30" Placeholder="Password:" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" IsPassword="True"/>
        <Image Source="Lock.png" Scale="0.6" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>

    <Button Text="Login"/>
</StackLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]